# Solr performance issues

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm using Solr to handle search on a very large set of documents, I start having performance issues with complex queries with facets and filters.
This is a solr query used to get some data :

solr full request : http://host/solr/discovery/select?q=*&fq=domain%3Acom+OR+host%3Acom+OR+public_suffix%3Acom&fq=crawl_date%3A%5B2000-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z+TO+2000-12-31T23%3A59%3A59Z%5D&fq=%7B%21tag%3Dcrawl_year%7Dcrawl_year%3A%282000%29&fq=%7B%21tag%3Dpublic_suffix%7Dpublic_suffix%3A%28com%29&start=0&rows=10&sort=score+desc&fl=*%2Cscore&hl=true&hl.fragsize=200&hl.simple.pre=%3Cstrong%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fstrong%3E&hl.snippets=10&hl.fl=content&hl.mergeContiguous=false&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=100000&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=11&facet.field=%7B%21ex%3Dcrawl_year%7Dcrawl_year&facet.field=%7B%21ex%3Ddomain%7Ddomain&facet.field=%7B%21ex%3Dpublic_suffix%7Dpublic_suffix&facet.field=%7B%21ex%3Dcontent_language%7Dcontent_language&facet.field=%7B%21ex%3Dcontent_type_norm%7Dcontent_type_norm&shards=shard1"

When this query is used localy with about 50000 documents, it takes about 10 seconds, but when I try it on host with 200 million documents it takes about 4 minutes. I know naturaly it's going to take a much longer time in the host, but I wonder if anyone had the same issue and was able to get faster results. Knowing that I'm using two Shards.

Waiting for your responses.

Comment: What version of Solr? You probably want to look at [Solr sparse faceting](https://tokee.github.io/lucene-solr/) which was created for something very similar to what your query indicates you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a number of complicated things at once: Date ranges, highlighting, faceting, and distributed search. (Non-solrcloud, looks like)

Still, 10 seconds for a 50k-doc index seems really slow to me. Try selectively *removing* aspects of your search to see if you can isolate which part is slowing things down and then focus on that. I'd expect that you can find simpler queries that are fast, even if they match a lot of documents.

Either way, check out https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#RAM

There are a lot of useful tips there, but the #1 performance issue is usually not having enough memory, especially for large indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Check for how many segments you have on solr 
as more the number of segments worse the query response 
If you have not set merge factor in your solrConfig.xml then probably you will have close 40 segments which is to bad for query response time 
Set your merge factor accordingly 
If no new documents are to be added set it 2

mergeFactor
The mergeFactor roughly determines the number of segments. 
The mergeFactor value tells Lucene how many segments of equal size to build before merging them into a single segment. It can be thought of as the base of a number system. 
For example, if you set mergeFactor to 10, a new segment will be created on the disk for every 1000 (or maxBufferedDocs) documents added to the index. When the 10th segment of size 1000 is added, all 10 will be merged into a single segment of size 10,000. When 10 such segments of size 10,000 have been added, they will be merged into a single segment containing 100,000 documents, and so on. Therefore, at any time, there will be no more than 9 segments in each index size. 
These values are set in the *mainIndex* section of solrconfig.xml (disregard the indexDefaults section): 
mergeFactor Tradeoffs
High value merge factor (e.g., 25): 
Pro: Generally improves indexing speed 
Con: Less frequent merges, resulting in a collection with more index files which may slow searching 
Low value merge factor (e.g., 2): 
Pro: Smaller number of index files, which speeds up searching. 
Con: More segment merges slow down indexing.